# Yocto zip download on every build

Tags: linux, embedded, yocto

Hi I would like to download in a bitbake recipe on every build from a http:// address! At the moment I am just able to download on the first build. Does anybody knows how I can force Yocto how to download on every build?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the download happens in do_fetch, this should do the trick:

```
do_fetch[nostamp] = "1"
```

From the [bitbake docs](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#variable-flags):

> [nostamp]: When set to "1", tells BitBake to not generate a stamp file for a task, which implies the task should always be executed.

Comment: Thank you. I tried with do_fetch[nostamp] = "1"! It doesn't work in my recipe. At the moment I solve my problem with bitbake "recipe" -f -c do_cleanall before I build my image